# Video content missing from Chrome Developer Tools Network Tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, google-chrome-devtools

The following website:
http://www.themedept.com/demo/getleads/agency.html

Shows a looping video:
http://www.themedept.com/demo/getleads/images/video/video.mp4

Why does this video video not appear in the Chrome Browser Developer Network Tools Tab:
[image]

Additional Information:
The video is called via Javascript which adds the following element to the page

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: visible; width: 1352px; height: auto;"><source src="images/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="images/video/video.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="images/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>
```

The Javascript that called this is from the file:
http://www.themedept.com/demo/getleads/js/plugins/jquery.vide.min.js

Comment: This is showing for me in the Network Tab. I searched for `mp4` and can see the entry. In fact, I can see a new `GET` for this video every time the loop starts, which doesn't seems correct. I'll screenshot my Network Tab when I can

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have the same issue (Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m) but I found that it at least works in an incognito session.

It seems that Chrome Dev Tools is not respecting the "Disable cache" setting for videos.

Comment: I have updated to Chrome 55. Noticed that the video.mp4 appears in incognito mode only.

Comment: I have filed a Chrome bug at CRBugs

Comment: @James I'm still experiencing the same thing. Do you have the URL of the bug report?

Comment: Only one that seems to fit is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649920

Comment: [Comment 9 in 670643](http://crbug.com/670643#c9) states you can navigate away and back again to reset the Dev Tools.

Comment: Still not fixed. Navigating away and back again works (tested in private mode), but not if you use the back button.

Answer (score 7):

The same problem in Mozilla FireFox.
You can use Private Window in FireFox for video src request.
Or Incognito in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you- same issue here, also in Firefox (Quantum)- as you say, an incognito window shows the request correctly. Bizarre. What is the reason for this... since it's happening in multiple browsers it seems this question requires an answer beyond "it's a bug..."

Answer (score 0):

I used MS edge Version 86.0.622.48 (I am on macOS Mojave) and it works just fine! For sending for those who have issues with Chrome and Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

still bug in 2021 in Chrome even with cache disabled and also didn't appear to work for incognito; does reflect properly in Mozilla/Firefox

it is reported properly in Lighthouse using Chrome so appears to be devtools bug