# How can I inspect HTML video in Chrome DevTools Network tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, html5-video

I'm trying to inspect the videostream of a html `<video>` tag, but Chrome DevTools Network tab doesn't show anything while the video is streaming.

The website is http://omegle.com , a live video chatroom.

Any hints?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870112/video-content-missing-from-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab

Comment: I already tried using incognito mode, doesn't help sadly

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, using incognito mode doesn't make any difference. The cache is disabled. Seeing this on Chrome 79 MacOS High Sierra